# Customer Decipher program c++ Trouble reading in

Tags: c++, arrays, encryption, dynamic, decode

So I have a custom decipher program that reads in an input file and deciphers it based on the keys that are input.
Text file:

```
23
11

Java 2 linux 3 fear 0 pool 2 do 0 red 1 lock. 1 I 0 random 2 computers, 0 not 0 the 0 open 2 car! 2 C, 0 lack 0 of 0 dog 1 green 2 C++ 0 bottle 2 wrong, 2 them. 0

5 1 10 21 9 6 21 11 13 16 20
```

This file is represented as:

```
[Number of Words]
[Number of Keys]

[Word] [Jump] [Word] [Jump] ... [Word] [Jump]   

[Key] [Key] ... [Key]
```

I have managed for the program to read in the number of keys and amount of words, however I have having trouble reading in the words and the numbers next to them as well as the last numbers and registering those as keys. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct pieces {

char word;
int jump;

} ;

 // Main Function
int main ()
{
// declare variables
int keyCount = 1;
int wordCount = 8;
int wordAmount[8];
int keyAmount[8];
pieces cipher[5];
char decoded[20][20];
char filename[10];
int keys[keyCount];
char tArray[20][20];
ifstream inData;

  //prompt user for input file

cout << " Enter file name: ";
cin >> filename;

inData.open(filename);

if(inData.is_open());
{

    // read list of names into array

    for ( int i = 0; i < keyCount; ++i){           

    inData >> wordAmount[i] >> keyAmount[i];

        for(int j = 0; j < wordCount; j++){

        inData >> cipher[j].word >> cipher[j].jump;

        }

    }

cout << " Key Count: " << keyCount << "\n";

    // print out 

        for ( int i = 0; i < keyCount; ++i){

    cout << " KeyAmount: ";
    cout << keyAmount[i] << "\n";
    cout << " WordAmount: ";
    cout << wordAmount[i] << "\n";

        for(int j = 0; j < wordCount; j++){

        cout << cipher[j].word << " " << cipher[j].jump;

            }

            }

    }

inData.close();

  return 0;
}
```

I did try putting the char word as an array but then I got a segmentation file. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I recommend using `char` for *single* characters and `std::string` for multiple characters (like words, sentences and *text lines*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, your project would be simpler if you used `std::string` and overloaded the formatted input operator `>>`:

```
struct Word_Jump
{
  std::string word; // Using std::string because it has space for more than one character.
  int jump;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Word_Jump& wj);
};

std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& input, Word_Jump& wj)
{
  input >> wj.word;
  input >> jump;
  return input;
}
```

Your input could look something like this:

```
std::vector<Word_Jump> database;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < number_of_words; ++i)
{
  Word_Jump wj;
  my_data_file >> wj;
  database.push_back(wj);
}
```

Similarly, you input for reading keys:

```
std::vector<int> key_database;
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < number_of_keys; ++j)
{
  int k = 0;
  my_data_file >> k;
  key_database.push_back(k);
}
```

So the above are two possible methods for reading in the word & jump pairs and also the keys.